# Integration Factor Constant Rule for Double Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I know that for the situation where there is a constant c on a function I can factor it from the integrand. So,

> $\int c f(x) dx$
>     $c \int f(x) dx$

What about a double integral? Would it be like

> $\iint c f(x,y) dx dy$
>      $c \iint f(x,y) dx dy$

Is that correct?

Comment: In a word: yes.

Comment: To see that this is so, imagine that $f$ is constant so that the double integral is the volume of a rectangular prism. If the situation is clear there, next, think about the definition of the integral as a limit of Riemann sums (if you know this, learn it if you don't) and general case should become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by definition $$ \iint f(x,y)dxdy =  \lim_{(\Delta x_i,\Delta y_j) \to (0,0)} \sum\sum f(\xi_i,\psi_j)\Delta x_i \Delta y_j$$

Now $$\iint cf(x,y)dxdy = \lim_{(\Delta x_i,\Delta y_j) \to (0,0)} \sum\sum cf(\xi_i,\psi_j)\Delta x_i \Delta y_j $$

Now, use the properties of Sums and limits to obtain:

$$\lim_{(\Delta x_i,\Delta y_j) \to (0,0)} \sum\sum cf(\xi_i,\psi_j)\Delta x_i \Delta y_j = c\left(\lim_{(\Delta x_i,\Delta y_j) \to (0,0)} \sum\sum f(\xi_i,\psi_j)\Delta x_i \Delta y_j\right) $$

Therefore,

$$\iint cf(x,y)dxdy = c\iint f(x,y)dxdy$$